# Laravel group route issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-routing

I'm using this code to implement admin area routes but `Route::get('/',...)` doesn't  work, it seems I should use anything other than `/` in `get` ,otherwise laravel doesn't load view when I browse to `mysite/admin/`.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('backend.index');
    });
    Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
});
```

UPDATE: there is an `admin` folder in `public` that is `public/admin`. It seems Laravel open this directory  instead of going through the route !
is it normal ?
 does public folder structure has priority to `Route::get()` ?

Comment: I checked your routes in my project , it seems it work fine. Whats your problem actually is? Can you show the folder structure of your view ?

Comment: It's not important what view is return, even if i do `return 'helllooo'` the exact result happen and that is showing the structure of  `public/admin` folder that contains js css and other stuff as shown [here](http://i63.tinypic.com/izrcat.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `admin` folder inside `public` folder it's normal that this directory content will be displayed but it's not Laravel issue.

If you look in `public/.htaccess` you have there something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

so if directory or file exists in `public` directory Laravel will not launch application but server will display this directory or this file. This is what should be done, because if there wouldn't be such rule no CSS files, JavaScript files or images could be displayed.

What you should do is either change directory name in `public` folder from `admin` to something else (and then make changes in your code to reflect this change) or change `admin` route to something else